# Ubuntu systemd service with some argument

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-18.04

```
$ echoip -h
Usage:
  echoip [OPTIONS]

Application Options:
  -f, --country-db=FILE        Path to GeoIP country database
  -c, --city-db=FILE           Path to GeoIP city database
  -a, --asn-db=FILE            Path to GeoIP ASN database
  -l, --listen=ADDR            Listening address (default: :8080)
  -r, --reverse-lookup         Perform reverse hostname lookups
  -p, --port-lookup            Enable port lookup
  -t, --template=FILE          Path to template (default: index.html)
  -H, --trusted-header=NAME    Header to trust for remote IP, if present (e.g. X-Real-IP)

Help Options:
  -h, --help                   Show this help message
```

The current config, which is working, is below, but i need to pass some arguments:

**I want command:**

```
ExecStart=/root/work/bin/echoip -c=/root/G.mmdb -f=/root/G1.mmdb -a=/root/A.mmdb -t=/root/goweb/bin/index.html
```

**Instead of**:

```
ExecStart=/root/goweb/bin/echoip
```

---

```
[Unit]
Description=goweb

[Service]
User=root
Type=forking
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/root/goweb/bin/echoip -c=/root/goweb/bin/data/city.mmdb -f=/root/goweb/bin/data/country.mmdb -a=/root/goweb/bin/data/asn.mmdb -t=/root/goweb/bin/index.html

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

Log:

```
journalctl -u goweb.service
```

---

```
Jan 20 13:55:49 ip systemd[1]: Starting goweb...
Jan 20 13:55:49 ip echoip[803]: echoip: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080
Jan 20 13:57:19 ip systemd[1]: goweb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 20 13:57:19 ip systemd[1]: goweb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 20 13:57:19 ip systemd[1]: Failed to start goweb.
Jan 20 13:57:24 ip systemd[1]: goweb.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 20 13:57:24 ip systemd[1]: goweb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jan 20 13:57:24 ip systemd[1]: Stopped goweb.
Jan 20 13:57:24 ip systemd[1]: Starting goweb...
Jan 20 13:57:24 ip echoip[1188]: echoip: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080
Jan 20 13:58:54 ip systemd[1]: goweb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 20 13:58:54 ip systemd[1]: goweb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 20 13:58:54 ip systemd[1]: Failed to start goweb.
```

Comment: You can add those parameters to the `ExecStart` line and reload the daemon ('`systemctl daemon-reload`).

Comment: Not working if add ExecStart=/root/work/bin/echoip -c=/root/G.mmdb -f=/root/G1.mmdb -a=/root/A.mmdb -t=/root/goweb/bin/index.html
But the command work on terminal

Comment: Can you add the logs of you service unit? `journalctl -u <name_of_your_unit>`

Comment: Here it is:
Jan 20 13:55:49 ip systemd[1]: Starting goweb...
Jan 20 13:55:49 ip echoip[803]: echoip: Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080
Jan 20 13:57:19 ip systemd[1]: goweb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jan 20 13:57:19 ip systemd[1]: goweb.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jan 20 13:57:19 ip systemd[1]: Failed to start goweb.

Comment: Most probably not related to your problem, but you shouldn't put this in `/root/`, and you shouldn't run services as the user `root` unless necessary. Rather create a service user for this.

Comment: My guess would be that the listening port (`8080`) is already taken. Check with `netstat -tlnp`, maybe another version of echoip is already running.

Comment: No only one process. when i stop there is no other process on 8080.
when i put only ExecStart=/root/goweb/bin/echoip working fine. Only problem when i give argument or arguments

Comment: I do not use the equal sign in passing echoip arguments:  *echoip -f /path/to/some/file...*. Take a look at the Wiki, https://github.com/mpolden/echoip/wiki/Running-Echo-IP-in-a-docker-with-Caddy-Reverse-proxying-with-Certs-from-Let's-encrypt